# Is swap enough for hibernating?

Tags: swap, hibernate

I have a PC with 4Gb RAM. I plan on extending it to 8Gb RAM.
This is my partition table.

[image]

Will the swap be enough for 8Gb RAM?
Or should I expect its 7.92Gb to fall short, even by a tiny amount?

Comment: It should be enough. I would allocate the swap-partition at the end of the disk though.

Comment: @David - As stated, I have 4Gb. Or I don't understand your point.

Comment: I have found that RAM * 1.5 is generally sufficient when hibernating on systems with less than 16GB. Once you go over 16GB, the caculation is: RAM + 6GB.

Comment: @David - Please check edited OP.

Comment: @matigo - I currently have more than 1.5*RAM (with 4Gb).
But if I extend it to 8Gb, I will certainly have less than 1.5*RAM. I would barely have 1.0*RAM, and then the question.

Comment: And there you go. 8GB * 1.5 = 12GB. Extend the swap to 12GB *as a contiguous file* (if this is the Toshiba notebook you're asking about [over here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400031/make-lubuntu-faster)) and you should be fine.

Comment: @matigo - Thanks, I might try that.
Would you think my current swap might not be enough for 8Gb RAM? If so, why?
I mean to understand if things are ok as they are now. And change that if really needed.

Comment: The thing to remember about swap when hibernating is the number of files that are held in the buffers. This is generally what makes hibernation tricky. 80% of the time things will be fine. One day, however, you'll have an extra tab open in Firefox and that'll blow through your swap budget making hibernation impossible, then you'll either have a notebook with no battery or a machine that won't wake up without a hard reset ...

Comment: @matigo - So you mean that, hibernating it with the current swap and 8Gb RAM, would work most of the times, and perhaps once in a while (of course, depending on my particular use, but I mean it for simple office/home stuff, no 3D rendering, heavy graphics, FF with 200 tabs, etc.) having a crash and needing a hard reboot?