# Make Lubuntu faster

Tags: lubuntu

I have an old laptop, Toshiba C855D-S5105.
I installed Lubuntu 20.04, expecting it to be light enough.
The PC works still quite slow.
I do not mean it to be blazing fast, but...

What steps can I take to have it run faster?

E.g., disabling services. These are what I have... What are good candidates?
The ones I would surely be using are
bluetooth, cron, lm-sensors, ssh, xrdp.

```
$ service --status-all
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ - ]  cryptdisks
 [ - ]  cryptdisks-early
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ - ]  gdomap
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ + ]  haveged
 [ + ]  hddtemp
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  lm-sensors
 [ - ]  lvm2
 [ - ]  lvm2-lvmpolld
 [ + ]  network-manager
 [ - ]  openvpn
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ - ]  plymouth-log
 [ - ]  pppd-dns
 [ + ]  preload
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  pulseaudio-enable-autospawn
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  saned
 [ + ]  sddm
 [ + ]  smartmontools
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ + ]  tlp
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ + ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common
 [ + ]  xrdp
```

.

```
$ systemctl --type=service
  UNIT                                                                                      LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION                       >
  accounts-daemon.service                                                                   loaded active running Accounts Service                  >
  acpid.service                                                                             loaded active running ACPI event daemon                 >
  alsa-restore.service                                                                      loaded active exited  Save/Restore Sound Card State     >
  apparmor.service                                                                          loaded active exited  Load AppArmor profiles            >
  apport.service                                                                            loaded active exited  LSB: automatic crash report genera>
  avahi-daemon.service                                                                      loaded active running Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack           >
  blk-availability.service                                                                  loaded active exited  Availability of block devices     >
  bluetooth.service                                                                         loaded active running Bluetooth service                 >
  console-setup.service                                                                     loaded active exited  Set console font and keymap       >
  cron.service                                                                              loaded active running Regular background program process>
  cups-browsed.service                                                                      loaded active running Make remote CUPS printers availabl>
  cups.service                                                                              loaded active running CUPS Scheduler                    >
  dbus.service                                                                              loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus          >
  dundee.service                                                                            loaded active running DUN service                       >
  haveged.service                                                                           loaded active running Entropy daemon using the HAVEGE al>
  hddtemp.service                                                                           loaded active exited  LSB: disk temperature monitoring d>
  irqbalance.service                                                                        loaded active running irqbalance daemon                 >
  kerneloops.service                                                                        loaded active running Tool to automatically collect and >
  keyboard-setup.service                                                                    loaded active exited  Set the console keyboard layout   >
  kmod-static-nodes.service                                                                 loaded active exited  Create list of static device nodes>
  lm-sensors.service                                                                        loaded active exited  Initialize hardware monitoring sen>
  lvm2-monitor.service                                                                      loaded active exited  Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapsh>
  ModemManager.service                                                                      loaded active running Modem Manager                     >
  networkd-dispatcher.service                                                               loaded active running Dispatcher daemon for systemd-netw>
  NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                        loaded active exited  Network Manager Wait Online       >
  NetworkManager.service                                                                    loaded active running Network Manager                   >
  ofono.service                                                                             loaded active running Telephony service                 >
  polkit.service                                                                            loaded active running Authorization Manager             >
  preload.service                                                                           loaded active running LSB: Adaptive readahead daemon    >
  rsyslog.service                                                                           loaded active running System Logging Service            >
  rtkit-daemon.service                                                                      loaded active running RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Serv>
  sddm.service                                                                              loaded active running Simple Desktop Display Manager    >
  setvtrgb.service                                                                          loaded active exited  Set console scheme                >
  smartmontools.service                                                                     loaded active running Self Monitoring and Reporting Tech>
  snapd.apparmor.service                                                                    loaded active exited  Load AppArmor profiles managed int>
  snapd.seeded.service                                                                      loaded active exited  Wait until snapd is fully seeded  >
  ssh.service                                                                               loaded active running OpenBSD Secure Shell server       >
  systemd-backlight@backlight:radeon_bl0.service                                            loaded active exited  Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightn>
  systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d432f01a\x2d285a\x2d44aa\x2dba33\x2d45a736457acc.service loaded active exited  File System Check on /dev/disk/by->
  systemd-journal-flush.service                                                             loaded active exited  Flush Journal to Persistent Storag>
  systemd-journald.service                                                                  loaded active running Journal Service                   >
  systemd-logind.service                                                                    loaded active running Login Service                     >
  systemd-modules-load.service                                                              loaded active exited  Load Kernel Modules               >
  systemd-random-seed.service                                                               loaded active exited  Load/Save Random Seed             >
  systemd-remount-fs.service                                                                loaded active exited  Remount Root and Kernel File Syste>
  systemd-resolved.service                                                                  loaded active running Network Name Resolution           >
  systemd-sysctl.service                                                                    loaded active exited  Apply Kernel Variables            >
  systemd-sysusers.service                                                                  loaded active exited  Create System Users               >
  systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                 loaded active running Network Time Synchronization      >
  systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                                        loaded active exited  Create Static Device Nodes in /dev>
  systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                            loaded active exited  Create Volatile Files and Director>
  systemd-udev-trigger.service                                                              loaded active exited  udev Coldplug all Devices         >
  systemd-udevd.service                                                                     loaded active running udev Kernel Device Manager        >
  systemd-update-utmp.service                                                               loaded active exited  Update UTMP about System Boot/Shut>
  systemd-user-sessions.service                                                             loaded active exited  Permit User Sessions              >
  tlp.service                                                                               loaded active exited  TLP system startup/shutdown       >
  udisks2.service                                                                           loaded active running Disk Manager                      >
  ufw.service                                                                               loaded active exited  Uncomplicated firewall            >
  upower.service                                                                            loaded active running Daemon for power management       >
  user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                                             loaded active exited  User Runtime Directory /run/user/1>
  user@1000.service                                                                         loaded active running User Manager for UID 1000         >
  whoopsie.service                                                                          loaded active running crash report submission daemon    >
  wpa_supplicant.service                                                                    loaded active running WPA supplicant                    >
  xrdp-sesman.service                                                                       loaded active running xrdp session manager              >
  xrdp.service                                                                              loaded active running xrdp daemon                       >

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

65 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

Comment: Could you please include the more updated overview: `systemctl --type=service`. The `service --status-all` command is rather ancient, and doesn't really give the full picture. Thanks.

Comment: If there is an HDD in it, replacing it with an SSD may help significantly. If you have a spare M.2 slot, you could install an NVME SSD for the OS and programs, and keep the HDD for storing large files.

Comment: Services will not be the problem unless you have found one that is heavy on writes. Based on the output that you've provided, none of the services currently running are going to sap performance. Does your Toshiba still have its factory 320GB HDD? If so, that drive is limited to moving data at 28.7MB/sec *if the data is sequentially placed on the disk*, which is going to be a massive bottleneck. The 1.3GHz CPU will also do you no favours as older machines rarely operate at peak efficiency 

Comment: @ArturMeinild - Done.

Comment: @matigo - Yes, I still have the original HD. If that is a bottleneck, I could try changing by a SSD. But if the 1.3GHz is, then there is no point. That's why I would try first the software-way, if it is not too time-consuming.

Comment: I would note here that I've run other distros on 32-bit machines with 300 MHz processor and < 768 MB RAM, and it wasn't unpleasant (though that's been several years).  There *are* lighter distros than Lubuntu around, if you search.  How up to date their kernels are and similar questions will remain.

Comment: @ZeissIkon raises a good point. If you are not wedded to Lubuntu, a distro like [Bodhi Linux](https://www.bodhilinux.com/) may suit the hardware. This is generally what I install on older systems.

Comment: How much (and what type) of RAM do you have in your PC? Also, Ubuntu actually has a minimum spec for a 2.4 GHz processor. Is your processor less? If it is, your computer will not run very well with Ubuntu. Either you could make some upgrades, or you could use another Linux distro (such as Arch, which is more lightweight than Ubuntu bu a long shot.)

Comment: Here is a guide that may help (on my website) It tells you how to install Arch Linux. https://oneenterprisestech.github.io/html/ht2.html

Comment: I'll suggest ensuring your apps share resources with your desktop... ie. user-behavior & thinking about what they run before it's started. I'm using Lubuntu on a 2009 dell currently, but QA-test on older & lighter boxes & used 32-bit boxes from 2003 & newer up to Lubuntu 19.04, but I was careful about what apps shared RAM to keep speed up (esp. on boxes with limited RAM).